# MASM array in procedure crashes program

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I get a crash whenever I execute code that has an array in a procedure, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I've done this succesfully before, but my new implementation makes it fail and crash  hard.

here's the part in main that sets up the whole thing:

```
push OFFSET list
push OFFSET looper
push OFFSET count
push tester
push OFFSET error_2
push OFFSET error_1
call validate
```

and here's the part of validate that crashes:

```
mov eax, [ebp + 16];
mov edx, [ebp+28]
mov ecx, [ebp+20]
mov [edx + 4 * ecx], eax ; this is the line that it crashes on
```

this is essentailly the same way I've accessed arrays in the past....what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to show the full code of `validate` (at least up to the point where it crashes), and the declaration of `tester`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you use EBP register? Address of return is in ESP, error_1 is in ESP+4, error_2 is in ESP+8, your tester is in ESP+0C...

Comment: sorry, the way I was taught was to pop ebp, then mov ebp, esp.  I forgot to include that code

Comment: Why POP EBP? You must PUSH EBP and then MOV EBP, ESP

Comment: that's what I meant, sorry.  Push ebp, move ebp, esp, then at the end pop ebp.  I found a workaround.